# powershell attach sql server database that has been detached by management studio

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am writing a powershell script that will automate a dev environment deployment and I've hit a problem with attaching the db's.  I am adding the 2 snap ins `SqlServerCmdletSnapin100` and `SqlServerProviderSnapin100` and using `SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\SQLEXPRESS` and the `AttachDatabase` method. This is working well and if I use `DetachDatabase` method in the same way I can re-run the script continually. My problem arises when I detach from the management studio and try to run the script again. No matter what I do here (permissions etc.) the script will continually fail from this point on with error:

```
Exception calling "AttachDatabase" with "2" argument(s): 
"Attach database failed for Server 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS'. "
```

If I change the name of the database I am attaching as the script will work again. Is there something in a system db that would be hanging onto the Database or database files that I need to remove as well?

Answer (score 1):

SMO uses nested error objects, so I'm wondering what the base error message states. If you run this statement:

`$error[0] | fl -force`

What error message do you get

Update
Ran a quick test:
Detach database "hsg" from my local instance using SSMS and successfully attached with this script:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\WIN7BOOT\SQL1> $s = get-item .
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\WIN7BOOT\SQL1> $s.AttachDatabase("hsg",$sc)
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\WIN7BOOT\SQL1> $sc = new-object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\WIN7BOOT\SQL1> $sc.Add("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL1\MSSQL\DATA\hsg.mdf")
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\WIN7BOOT\SQL1> $sc.Add("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL1\MSSQL\DATA\hsg_log.ldf)
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, the error is: Cannot attach a database with the same name as an existing database.
I've now hit refresh 5 times through management studio :) the database is not in the database list at least.

Comment: UPDATE running DetachDatabase after getting the above error gives me another error: Detach failed... Database does not exist

Comment: I'm unable to repo your issue. One other suggestion try refreshing databases in powershell PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\WIN7BOOT\SQL1> get-item . | %{$_.databases.refresh()}

Answer (score 1):

I detached a database using SQL Server Management Studio and used the following code to attach the database back to the same instance. It worked Ok except that the attached database did not get the original name although files were the same.

```
PS SQLSERVER:\sql\Hodentek8\RegencyPark\databases> 
$files = new-object system.collections.specialized.stringcollection

$files.add("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL11.REGENCYPARK\MSSQL\DATA\Feb6.mdf")


$files.add("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.REGENCYPARK\MSSQL\DATA\Feb6_log.ldf")

$server=new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server('Hodentek8\RegencyPark')

$db=new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server

$dbname="feb6"

$server.AttachDatabase($db,$files)
```

Some details are here:
http://hodentekmsss.blogspot.com/2015/04/attaching-detached-database-in-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

perhaps instead of localhost\SQLExpress you should use:
I found this fix for some of my code which returned the same error:

```
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server 'Hodentek8\RegencyPark'
```

## Replace 'Hodentek8\RegencyPark' by ("(local)") for the default instance

Example here:
http://hodentekmsss.blogspot.com/2015/04/counting-sql-server-configuration.html